# Trouble using asynctask in ftp-client program in android

Tags: android, ftp, android-asynctask

I was working with an android ftp project. It will run only on `sdk` below or 2.3, for that i implemented `asynctask` and tested it on `jellybean` but it is not working properly someone please help me to make whole this activity as a background thread.

**code**

```
package com.example.ftptest;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class UploadActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "UploadActivity";
    private ListView maLV;
    private String pass, host, user;
    private int port;
    private MyFTPClient ftpClient;
    private FTPFile[] ftpFiles;
    private File fileLocal;
    public FTPFile fileServer, folderServer;
    Context context;
    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);
        context = this;
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        // retrieves donnéees
        Bundle extra = this.getIntent().getExtras();

        if (extra != null) {
            pass = extra.getString("pass");
            host = extra.getString("host");
            user = extra.getString("user");
            port = extra.getInt("port");
        }
        // connects to the FTP Server
        ftpClient = new MyFTPClient();
        Log.d(TAG, "HOST " + host);
        Log.d(TAG, "USER " + user);
        Log.d(TAG, "PASS " + pass);
        Log.d(TAG, "PORT " + port);
        ///////////////////// // use asynctask

        uploadRefresh();
        downloadRefresh();

        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                downloadRefresh();
            }

        });

        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                uploadRefresh();
            }

        });

        Button upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);
        upload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {


                    uploadRefresh();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    System.out.println("sarath:from upload");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        Button download = (Button) findViewById(R.id.download);
        download.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {

                    // Refresh list // use asynctask
                    downloadRefresh();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("sarath:from upload");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private File[] localFiles;

    public void localPrintFilesList(File dir, String header) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "getting local data directories");
            maLV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            localFiles = dir.listFiles();
            int length = localFiles.length;

            // Creating the ArrayList that will allow us to feed the listView
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItem = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            // It says HashMap that contains the information for an item
            HashMap<String, String> map;

            // String[] values = new String[length];
            Log.d(TAG, "number of file in the directory: " + length);
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                // initialization of HashMap
                map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                String name = localFiles[i].getName();
                boolean isFile = localFiles[i].isFile();
                // values[i] = name;
                if (isFile) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "File : " + name);
                    map.put("img", String.valueOf(R.drawable.file));
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Directory : " + name);
                    map.put("img", String.valueOf(R.drawable.folder));
                }
                map.put("title", name);

                // Add to watchlist
                listItem.add(map);
            }

            // ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            // R.layout.listviewitem, android.R.id.text1, values);
            SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this.getBaseContext(),
                    listItem, R.layout.listviewitem, new String[] { "img",
                            "title" }, new int[] { R.id.img, R.id.title });
            // TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            // tv.setText(header);
            // maLV.addHeaderView(tv);
            maLV.setAdapter(mSchedule);

            maLV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Position : " + position);
                    Log.i(TAG, "longueur liste : " + localFiles.length);
                    // On regarde si c'est un file ou un dossier
                    boolean isFile = localFiles[position].isFile();
                    if (isFile) {
                        fileLocal = localFiles[position];
                    } else {
                        localPrintFilesList(localFiles[position],
                                localFiles[position].getName());
                    }

                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void serverPrintFilesList(String ftpDir, String header)// use
                                                                    // asynctask
    {
        try {
            maLV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView2);
            Log.d(TAG, "recuperation des données du repertoires");
            ftpFiles = ftpClient.mFTPClient.listFiles(ftpDir);
            for (FTPFile ftpliste : ftpFiles) {
                Log.d(TAG, "liste des repertoire : " + ftpliste.getName());
            }
            int length = ftpFiles.length;
            Log.d(TAG, "nombre de file dans le repertoire : " + length);
            // Création de la ArrayList qui nous permettra d'alimenter la
            // listView
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItem = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            // On déclare la HashMap qui contiendra les informations pour un
            // item
            HashMap<String, String> map;

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                String name = ftpFiles[i].getName();
                boolean isFile = ftpFiles[i].isFile();

                if (isFile) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "File : " + name);
                    map.put("img", String.valueOf(R.drawable.file));
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Directory : " + name);
                    map.put("img", String.valueOf(R.drawable.folder));
                }
                map.put("title", name);

                // Ajoute à la liste
                listItem.add(map);
            }

            // ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            // R.layout.listviewitem, android.R.id.text1, values);
            SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this.getBaseContext(),
                    listItem, R.layout.listviewitem, new String[] { "img",
                            "title" }, new int[] { R.id.img, R.id.title });
            // TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            // tv.setText(header);
            // maLV.addHeaderView(tv);
            maLV.setAdapter(mSchedule);

            maLV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // On récupère le titre de l'Item dans un String
                    boolean isFile = ftpFiles[position].isFile();
                    if (isFile) {
                        fileServer = ftpFiles[position];
                    } else {
                        folderServer = ftpFiles[position];
                        serverPrintFilesList(ftpFiles[position].getName(),
                                ftpFiles[position].getName());// use asynctask
                    }

                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void downloadRefresh() {
        // refresh the list
        Log.d(TAG, "before recovery of directory");
        File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        Log.d(TAG, "after recovery of the directory");
        Log.d(TAG, dir.toString());
        localPrintFilesList(dir, "LOCAL FILES");

    }

    public void uploadRefresh() {
        // Refresh the uploadlist
        Log.d(TAG,
                "List directory of server1 : "
                        + ftpClient.ftpGetCurrentWorkingDirectory());
        try {
            serverPrintFilesList(ftpClient.ftpGetCurrentWorkingDirectory(),
                    "SERVER FILES");// use asynctask
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d(TAG, "Unable to retrieve the list  ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private class BackTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // show process dialog
            pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
            pd.setTitle("File operation");
            pd.setMessage("Please wait.");
            pd.setCancelable(true);
            pd.setIndeterminate(true);
            pd.show();

        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(params[0] == "connect")
            {
                ftpClient.ftpConnect(host, user, pass, port);
            }
            else if(params[0] == "download")
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "download");
                Log.i(TAG, "file : " + fileServer.getName());
                // Log.i(TAG, "folder : " + folderLocal.getName());
                ftpClient.ftpDownload(fileServer.getName(), Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory().getName()
                        + "/"
                        + fileServer.getName());
            }
            else if(params[0] == "upload")
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "upload");

                System.out
                        .println("--------------------------------------------------------------");

                System.out.println("srcFilePath = " + fileLocal.getPath());
                System.out.println("file = "
                        + fileLocal.getPath().replace("/mnt", ""));
                System.out.println("desDirectory = " + "/");

                ftpClient
                        .ftpUpload(fileLocal.getPath().replace("/mnt", ""));
            }
            else if(params[0] == "getdir")
            {
                uploadRefresh();
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("Bingo! ", "Connected");
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String c)
        {
            pd.cancel();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Long running operations you should be managed from a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), not an Activity which can stop at any time (for example another application starts).

AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)

In your case I would suggest to use a thread and a handler to receive messages from the thread:

```
public class BackTask extends Thread{
...
    public void run(){
        // do time consuming tasks

        Message messageToParent = new Message();
        Bundle messageData = new Bundle();
        messageToParent.what = 0;
        messageData.putString(".....", ".....");
        messageToParent.setData(messageData);
        ThreadHandler.sendMessage(messageToParent);
    }
}
```

Message handler:

```
public Handler HttpThreadHandler = new Handler(){

    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg){
        Bundle resBundle = msg.getData();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.